# Google glass voice prompt customization

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

How to customize voice prompt for google glass app? When glassware launches, using voice prompt microphone icon and single string (customizable) is displayed. Is there a way to customize microphone icon and string appearance? For example add additional smaller text to prompt explanation?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <trigger keyword="@string/glass_voice_trigger">
     <input prompt="@string/glass_voice_prompt" />
  </trigger>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with the current API: feel free to file a feature request on our [issues tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list).